# rook polynomials

Tags: co.combinatorics

Rook polynomial of a chess board is known. I am curious if there is a higher dimensional torus version of the polynomial? How about the corresponding cases for Queen's/King's problem? Are there any references available?

Answer (score 2):

Rook polynomials can be interpreted as generating functions for subsets consisting of pairwise non-adjacent vertices in graphs (such subsets are called independent sets). Indeed, consider the graph with vertices all cases under consideration with edges joining cases having an equal coordinate.

The algorithm for computing such polynomials is the same: a vertex either belongs or does not belong to a given independent set and this gives a recursion over subgraphs with either
the vertex and all its neighbours removed or only the vertex removed.

The torus version does not change anything: moves of rooks on chessboards and on the obvious analogous toric chessboards are the same.

Higher dimensional analogues are for instance useful (at least theoretically) for the construction of schedules of schools: one dimension for classes, one for teachers, one for classrooms and one for time-slots.

Queen's and King's problems can of course be solved similarly by considering a graph with 
edges joining all adjacent cases (King) or all cases related horizontally or diagonally (Queen).

Comment: Is there references for Kings polynomials in the case of higher dimensional tori?

Comment: or any of the works on higher dimensional tori?